# Spock mock multiple interfaces

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock

I have a Jax-WS Webservice call which is enclosed in a class which I need to test using spock.
The implementation of the webservice call is done in a superclass which I can't change. I would prefer to do a redesign and get rid of the inheritance but I can't do that.

For my unit test I wan't to mock the webservice. The code which creates the port looks like this:

```
MyPortType client = createServiceClient(); //inherited from superclass, needs to be mocked
(BindingProvider) bp = (BindingProvider) client;
```

That cast to `BindingProvider` is always safe with JAX-WS, so that's not a problem. However I need to mock the `createServiceClient()` method and I need it to return a mock which implements both `MyPortType` and `BindingProvider`.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
MyPortType port = Mock(MyPortType) as BindingProvider
port.myMethod(_ as MyType) >> Mock(MyResponse)
```

But I get this exception:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class $Proxy541_groovyProxy does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract MyResponse myMethod(MyType)' of interface MyPortType.
```

I suspect that I'm still defining the `MyPortType` Mock the wrong way, but I can't figure it out.

Has anybody tried this kind of thing before?

**EDIT**: Both of these return true, so it would seem, that the mock for the class works, but the mock for the method does not:

```
port instanceof MyPortType
port instanceof BindingProvider
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `Mock(MyPortType, additionalInterfaces: [BindingProvider])`, i.e. [A la Carte Mocks](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.1/all_in_one.html#ALaCarteMocks).
However, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1405) which prevents defining responses for the additional interfaces methods, so it will only pass `instanceof` checks. As a workaround you can define a test interface that extends both interfaces.

```
interface TestPortType extends MyPortType, BindingProvider {}
// ...
TestPortType port = Mock(TestPortType)
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was after. And I did run into the issue you linked, so thanks for pointing that out.